# How to unpivot from a long to a wide table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

My data in `testtable`:

| FechaRegistro | IdRecordRedcap | FechaRegistro | diario_total_pruebas | diario_pruebas_negativas | diario_pruebas_rechazadas |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | 15 | 2022-01-06 | 510 | 384 | NULL |

I require to unpivot the following data without the `UNPIVOT` function

| FechaRegistro | IdRecordRedcap | Var | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-06 | 15 | diario_total_pruebas | 510 |
| 2022-01-06 | 15 | diario_pruebas_negativas | 384 |
| 2022-01-06 | 15 | diario_pruebas_rechazadas | *null* |

[Structure and sample data in this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f9a31a460b3850b55ecb9055d8fd397d)

Comment: _my sql server engine doesnt have it_ What exactly does that mean? You are not using SQL Server? For a fixed set of columns, conditional aggregation is an option.

Comment: Thats unpivot??

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using that does not have PIVOT / UNPIVOT?  All supported versions have it.  I highly recommend you investigate upgrading.

Comment: What have you tried? And if your version of sql server doesn't have PIVOT/UNPIVOT you are WAY LONG overdue to upgrade your sql server version to something released in the last decade.

Comment: Im sorry but upgrading is not up to me

Comment: So what version do you have so we know what IS supported on your SQL Server instance?  And upgrading may not be up to you but you should certainly push for it...

Comment: @AndresMora PIVOT/UNPIVOT is an old command. If it's missing, it means your version is 20 years old at least. A laptop with SQL Server Express will havemore cores and RAM than whatever you use right now

Comment: I might be misremembering, but weren't `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT` added in SQL Server 2005? That would mean you're using SQL Server 2000 or prior!

Comment: @AndresMora without `UNPIVOT` you'll have to UNION as many times as there are columns and retrieve their values.

Comment: @Larnu that's what I was thinking also, that those were released with 2005.

Comment: I trust your memory better than mine then, @SeanLange . I wasnt even classified as an adult in 2000, so never used it.

Comment: @Larnu it 100% was not available in 2000. I spent a lot of hours wrestling that old beast far past the end of its life cycle.

Comment: @SeanLange and when it was introduced everyone complained that PIVOT wasn't really better than the GROUP BY statements we used to write. Which was quite accurate. UNPIVOT was the real improvement

Comment: @SeanLange and Aaron either created or wrote about all the available unpivoting techniques back then

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos indeed. Learned a lot of things from him then and now.

Comment: @AndresMora I really do recommend you run `PRINT @@VERSION` against your instance and then tag the version is says you're using (or at least put the output into the comments).

Comment: `Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2) (KB3171021) - 12.0.5000.0 (X64)   
 Jun 17 2016 19:14:09   
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  
 Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)`

Comment: @AndresMora why don't you use UNPIVOT then? BTW `Developer` was *not* free in SQL Server 2014. It became free in 2016. It was never meant to be used in production either, so whatever edition your production database is, it's not `Developer`.

Comment: For only three columns I find the UNION ALL approach a little easier to follow. This would be less true if there were no NULLs to handle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
-- on SQL Server 2000 you must have a death wish

  SELECT FechaRegistro, IdRecordRedcap,
         Var   = 'diario_total_pruebas',
         Value =  diario_total_pruebas 
  FROM dbo.testtable

  UNION ALL

  SELECT FechaRegistro, IdRecordRedcap,
         Var   = 'diario_pruebas_negativas',
         Value =  diario_pruebas_negativas 
  FROM dbo.testtable

  UNION ALL

  SELECT FechaRegistro, IdRecordRedcap,
         Var   = 'diario_pruebas_rechazadas',
         Value =  diario_pruebas_rechazadas 
  FROM dbo.testtable;
```

To be fair, to have the `UNPIVOT` solution on versions published this century deal with `NULL`s correctly, it's not that much cleaner:

```
-- on SQL Server 2005 and later

;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT FechaRegistro, IdRecordRedcap, 
    diario_total_pruebas      = COALESCE(diario_total_pruebas,      -1),
    diario_pruebas_negativas  = COALESCE(diario_pruebas_negativas,  -1),
    diario_pruebas_rechazadas = COALESCE(diario_pruebas_rechazadas, -1)
  FROM dbo.testtable
)
SELECT FechaRegistro, IdRecordRedcap, 
       Var, Value = NULLIF(Value, -1)
  FROM x UNPIVOT 
  (
     Value FOR Var IN
     (
       diario_total_pruebas,
       diario_pruebas_negativas,
       diario_pruebas_rechazadas
     )
  ) AS u;
```

Output in both cases:

| FechaRegistro | IdRecordRedcap | Var | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-06 | 15 | diario_total_pruebas | 510 |
| 2022-01-06 | 15 | diario_pruebas_negativas | 384 |
| 2022-01-06 | 15 | diario_pruebas_rechazadas | *null* |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fb90ccde3b651bc7d677a0e0bb7b4e8f)

Comment: Wonder what Joe Celko would have said back then if anyone used `Var   = 'diario_pruebas_negativas'` :P. I miss those days

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it would have been a novel with formatting and grammar that made it almost impossible to read and decipher all the condescension about why we got away from tapes. ;)

Answer (score 1):

UNPIVOT was introduced with SQL Server 2005. If you really use SQL Server 2000 you have far bigger problems than UNPIVOTing. A laptop with SQL Server Express is far more powerful with far faster disks, far more RAM and CPU cores than anything available 20 years ago (multicore wasn't a thing yet). And far safer too.

Without UNPIVOT you can have to write as many queries as there are columns to unpivot and combine them with `UNION ALL` :

```
select FechaRegistro,IdRecordRedcap,'diario_total_pruebas' as Var,
diario_total_pruebas as Value
from testtable
UNION ALL
select FechaRegistro,IdRecordRedcap,'diario_pruebas_negativas' as Var,
diario_pruebas_negativas   as Value
from testtable
...
```